# Am I charged for batch operations that not succeed in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a batch that contains exactly 200 operations. I know that if I get an error, none of them are applied. The question is, am I still charged with 200 writes, even if the batch does not succeed? Or am I not charged at all in this situation?

Comment: Why would the batch write fail?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Then why the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) stands for, "either all of the operations succeed, or none of them are applied"? I'm talking about the second case when "none of them are applied". That's why I'm asking. A batch cannot fail? I'm confused. Can you help me with that?

Comment: The logic for charges is quite simple: if a document is written on the server, you are charged for a document write. If a document is read from the server, you are charged a document read.

Without knowing why your batch write fails, it's hard to say anything about charges. When in doubt: I recommend testing it, which conveniently also requires that you create the failure that I'm asking you to be specific about.